# Have an Input/output error when connecting to a server via ssh

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

Hello I seem to be having a problem while connecting to a Ubuntu Server while connecting via ssh. When I login, I get this error.

```
Could not chdir to home directory /home/username: Input/output error
```

It seems like my home folder is corrupt or something. I cannot ls in the home folder directory, and in my usename directory, I can't cd into this. As root I cannot ls in the home directory as well or in any directory in Home.

I notice as well when I save in vim or quit, it get this error at the bottom of the page

```
E138: Cannot write viminfo file /home/root/.viminfo!
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT**: this is what happens if I type in these commands

`mount`

```
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
none on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
none on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
none on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /var/run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,mode=0755)
none on /var/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
/dev/mapper/RAID1-lvvar on /var type xfs (rw)
/dev/mapper/RAID5-lvsrv on /srv type xfs (rw)
/dev/mapper/RAID5-lvhome on /home type xfs (rw)
/dev/mapper/RAID1-lvtmp on /tmp type reiserfs (rw)
```

`dmesg | tail`

```
[1213273.364040] Filesystem "dm-3": xfs_log_force: error 5 returned.
[1213274.084081] Filesystem "dm-4": xfs_log_force: error 5 returned.
[1213309.364038] Filesystem "dm-3": xfs_log_force: error 5 returned.
[1213310.084041] Filesystem "dm-4": xfs_log_force: error 5 returned.
[1213345.364039] Filesystem "dm-3": xfs_log_force: error 5 returned.
[1213346.084042] Filesystem "dm-4": xfs_log_force: error 5 returned.
[1213381.365036] Filesystem "dm-3": xfs_log_force: error 5 returned.
[1213382.084047] Filesystem "dm-4": xfs_log_force: error 5 returned.
[1213417.364039] Filesystem "dm-3": xfs_log_force: error 5 returned.
[1213418.084063] Filesystem "dm-4": xfs_log_force: error 5 returned.
```

`fdisk -l /dev/sda`

```
Cannot open /dev/sda
```

Answer (score 1):

It is probably due to home partition filesystem corrupted. Please, show outputs of following commands: `mount`, `dmesg | tail`, `fdisk -l /dev/sda`

Answer (score 0):

If this is a problem with your ~ partition then you will need to create a new one, there is a nice [howto](http://vsltd.co/fKct3P) on how to do this. In your case you may not be able to copy over the existing files but the howto is useful still.

Answer (score 0):

Before you clean the partition, you should check /etc/fstab to see how /home is mounted.  If it is listed there as a separate partition, then try "mount" to see if it is mounted or "mount -a" to force it to try and mount.

You should do all of this locally and not through ssh, in order to rule out ssh issues.